# Acumatica Email not being send anymore. MS office 365 changed SMTP encryption to STARTTLS

Tags: email, smtp, settings, acumatica

Email is not being sent anymore although it worked before and no settings were changed.

I found out that the MS Office 365 SMTP setting now uses encryption method STARTTLS which is not listed in the Acumatica email advanced server settings. Is this the problem?

I have also submitted a support ticket but wanted to share this with other Acumatica users in to solicit possible fixes.

Comment: Which POP3/SMTP ports are you using in Acumatica configuration? (Configuration->Email->Manage->System Email Accounts->Advanced Settings)

Comment: SSL/TLS setting is in Outgoing server encrypted connection in the same tab. Usually port numbers follow standard and by knowing the port number we can determine what settings we should use.